# Export material values (metalness/roughness) to WebGL

Tags: export, webgl

I would try to find the answer myself but time is against us.

I and my colleague are working on WebGL for the webpage. I'm making the 3D parts of this process and he takes care of the coding.
Does somebody know if values like Metalness, roughness (no textures, just values like 0.7 and 0.5) are possible to export in glb, or does this need to be setup again directly in WebGL by my colleague?

If both options are possible, which one is better in terms of time and difficulty?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glTF (`.gltf` or `.glb`) format includes a metal/rough PBR material that does support metalness and roughness properties — either values or textures — like you're describing. In Blender, you'll want to choose the Principled BSDF material, configure those properties, and export. The [Blender glTF documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) has more details on which material configurations are supported for export. Common WebGL engines like three.js and Babylon.js will handle these materials correctly.